# Is it possible to use fingerprint on X1 Yoga 1st GEN in Ubuntu

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I would like to ask you if is there possibility to use fingerprint on X1 Yoga 1st Gen (Type 20FQ, 20FR) Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20FR - Model 20FRS01V00 in Ubuntu. Are there drivers for it?
I did not find drivers and information for it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please upload a probe to "linuxhardware" and add the link to the question. https://linux-hardware.org/

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @Marco points out, you can generate a probe. As well, please edit your question to include the output of the following command: `lsusb`. This should list the device hardware used on your laptop. From there check the [fprint project site](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) to check if your hardware ID is listed.

Comment: It is not in the list and also my integrated camera is not in the list.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7500 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:705a Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:503f Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub